# Azure SQL Managed Instance with private IP vitual nework

Tags: azure-sql-managed-instance

We have a Org policy which does not allow public IP for resource creation and because of that I am not able to create SQL Managed Instance as it takes public IP in Virtual network. Is there a way to configure the virtual network with private IP for SQL Managed Instance?

below is the policy:

"properties": {
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "description": "Security policy we do not allow public ip addresses and user defined routes",
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "source": "action",
            "like": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/*"
          },
          {
            "source": "action",
            "like": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/*"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Managed instance by default gets private IP address assigned for data traffic, and you can open an additional public IP address as an opt-in feature. 
If you are referring to instance's [management endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-connectivity-architecture#management-endpoint), for instance management traffic, please notice that it is necessary for managed instance to work and protected by a [built-in firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-management-endpoint-verify-built-in-firewall).

Comment: I have added the policy in my question. Can you please take a look and suggest the ways to handle it?